# Win10: Assigned Access, can't select user

Tags: windows-10

I'm having some issues creating an Assigned Access in Win10. At first, I was able to select a user but after I had to remove the user due to complications but when I made a new user and wanted to select him and assign an application to that user, all I got back was a blank section and I can't select users anymore. I have looked and searched the internet for answers but so far have not found anything that solves my problems.

Do you know a way to fix this? Based on guides here instead of a blank section I should see a + sign and select user message. Really would like to avoid re-installing windows.

[Screenshot of the assigned access section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg5z4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following way to troubleshoot the issue or resolve the issue:

1. Check the version of Windows 10, we need to have Windows 10 Pro, Windows 10 Enterprise, or Windows 10 Education installed on our computer.
2. We have installed the Universal Windows app for the Assigned Access user accounts.
3. Have we successfully set up signed access for a user account? If no, maybe a computer policy blocked this feature.
4. If we change the current logon account, then change a user account or a administrator account to long on the computer, can we set up assigned access successfully? If it is related to the currently logged in user, it may be necessary to have a privileged account to set it up. Or maybe a user policy has blocked this feature.
5. If the above does not work, we can configure assigned access using PowerShell:

Configure assigned access by user name and AppUserModelID

Configure assigned access by user name and app name

Configure assigned access by user SID and AppUserModelID

Configure assigned access by app name and user SID

For detailed PowerShell commands, we can refer the articles: [Configure assigned access](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/configure-assigned-access-by-using-the-ui)